# SoapUI Pro 3.0.1 SocketTimeOut Exception:ReadTimeout

Tags: exception, soapui

I am using SOAP UI Pro and when accessing any of the exposed methods in the services it always gives me SocketTimeOut Exception:ReadTimeout

Any idea???

Comment: See my answer at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706055/wcf-webservices-times-out-from-soapui/13989176#13989176. how 
to setup 
WS-A tab in SoapUI project for wsHttpBinding service

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I changed the endpoint binding from "wsHttpBinding" to "basicHttpBinding" in the config file. "wsHttpBinding" incorporates a lot of the newer web services standards, which means that older clients may have trouble using this binding. "basicHttpBinding" works a lot like the older asmx web services. Here is a good link describing the differences: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/HttpBinding.aspx