# WCF webservices times out from SoapUI

Tags: c#, wcf, soapui

I have the following in a WCF project .Net 4.0:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface EchoService {
    [OperationContract]
    void Ping();
}

[ServiceBehavior]
public class EchoServiceImpl : EchoService {
    public void Ping() { }
}
```

Wether I deploy to IIS, or run in the debugger, when I connect from SoapUI and try to invoke the ping command, I eventually get a timeout. My intention is to generate a service that can be called from Java, but I can't even get a noop ping command to work currently.

Is there any way to debug what's going on?

Comment: Seems I can't get it working with wsHttpBindings in Web.config. basicHttpBindings work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to wsHttpBinding service and getting timeouts in SoapUI project

> Open the first request
>   and press the WS-A button (on the bottom of the request editor). Check
>   “Enable WS-A addressing”, “Add default wsa:Action” and “Add default
>   wsa:To”.

(From http://berendjdejong.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/soapui-and-wcf-service-testing/)

After these changes I was able to properly communicate with WCF service.

See more details about WS-A at http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/using-ws-addressing.html

Answer (score 0):

For wsHttpBinding you need to use security of some sort if you're hosting it in IIS you'll need to set a certificate.