# WCF wsHttpBinding in SoapUI

Tags: wcf, soapui

I am trying to add WCF service with `wsHttpBinding` to soapUI.

I am using message security and it works with test client but SoapUI returns

> An error occurred when verifying security for the message

Here is service configuration:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
   <binding name="wsHttpSecure">
      <security mode="Message">
         <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"    
                  establishSecurityContext="false" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
   </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

Here http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/applying-ws-security.html is a document but they say I need .jks file. I only have encoded public key value generated by SvcUtil in test client configuration file.

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13989176/52277  how 
to setup 
WS-A tab in SoapUI project for wsHttpBinding service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this setting is not interoperable with soapUI:

```
negotiateServiceCredential="true"
```

change it to false

Comment: Do you have a source to confirm that soapUI does not support that setting?

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, they have this entire section on this very topic http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/applying-ws-security.html - what is that about?

Comment: negotiateServiceCredential uses ssl negotiated which is wcf proprietary standard. it is not part of the standard ws-security. while other products can try to implement it this has never been done.

Answer (score 11):

after a lot of research I found a solution on a blog.

You need to check the WS-A:To checkbox, located on the WS-A options tab.

[image: How to enable wsa:To]

After doing that, my problem was solved.

[This is the blog containing the solution. Thanks David!!](http://ddkonline.blogspot.com.br/2012/10/wcf-45-host-unreachable-when-calling.html)