# WCF Service with username security not working

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, ws-security

I created few wcf services before but never implemented security. Now I am trying to implement username security for my wcf service. Upon some research, implemented the security on the service using wsHttpBinding. But when i try to test the service with SOAPUI tool, i am getting some weird message and can't find whats wrong. Please help me to find whats wrong here.

Here is my validation class.

```
namespace WDARProductsService
{
    public class MyAuthentication : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
                throw new SecurityTokenException("userName required");

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
                throw new SecurityTokenException("password required");

            if (userName.ToLower() != "someusername" && password != "somepassword")
                throw new FaultException("userName and/or password is invalid.");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my wcf configuration.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="svcbhvr1">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WDARProductsService.MyAuthentication, WDARProductsService"/>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="WDARProdService"
                          storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                          storeName="Root"
                          x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wshbinding">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WDARProductsService.ProductService" behaviorConfiguration="svcbhvr1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wshbinding" contract="WDARProductsService.IProductService" ></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Here is the SOAP message i am sending from SOAPUI.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-38DE8B83BF5FAA37EE13984444482027">
        <wsse:Username>someusername</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">somepassword</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">vkis9SvbH3lnvdNWR/L5nA==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2014-04-25T16:47:28.202Z</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <tem:GetProducts>
    </tem:GetProducts>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here is the response from the server.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</a:Action>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <s:Code>
            <s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
            <s:Subcode>
               <s:Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">a:BadContextToken</s:Value>
            </s:Subcode>
         </s:Code>
         <s:Reason>
            <s:Text xml:lang="en-US">The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://tempuri.org/IProductService/GetProducts' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.</s:Text>
         </s:Reason>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Can anybody help me please to find whats the issue. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

By default WsHttpBinding with Security set to Message will enable security context:
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpsecurity.message.aspx

So before you sent a message containing the username token. You need to establish secure conversation. I don't know if it's supported in SoapUI, but there you can find some tips:
[WCF wsHttpBinding in SoapUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169871/wcf-wshttpbinding-in-soapui)

If you don't want to use secure conversation, set establishSecurityContext to false. If you're planning to use it in production consider using TransportWithMessageCredential to encrypt the message with SSL.